403 for image reported by ahref but not found in source of dev tools
I am facing a strange issue, i did audit my website and noticed score has gone down in last few months upon checking i notice it reports 403 error on almost every page for image link
https://www.example.com/images/page/
while my normal image path is https://www.example.com/images/page/f561a540-fba4-463d-8884-dd6d3e87sd9.jpg
I cross checked all the source code however i am not able to find any broken link on the page as https://www.example.com/images/page/
i inspected in web developer tool but no such error is noticed as all assets are loaded and i don't seen any 403 error.
I did another ahref audit however it reports same 403 error for https://www.example.com/images/page/ i am not sure what is causing this any idea what could be causing this or any pointer as all assets load when i test them on chrome dev tools.

Have you tried crawling your site with other tools? Depending on your website size, you can use some of the free trials.
